# How to Plot Surface Plot / 3-D Laplace Transform for x(t) = exp(-t)sin(t) with SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

This is what I want to achieve:

[image: 3]

I have this function `x(t) = exp(-t)*sin(t)` that will undergone a Laplace transform x(s) :

[image: 2]

and

[image: 1]

I have this code but unable to do the 3-D plot for the Laplace Transform toward the function `x(t)`, or how to break `s` into `α + iω`.

```
import sympy
sympy.init_printing()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t, s = sympy.symbols('t, s')
a = sympy.symbols('a', real=True, positive=True)

def L(f):
    return sympy.laplace_transform(f, t, s, noconds=True)

def invL(F):
    return sympy.inverse_laplace_transform(F, s, t)

f1 = sympy.exp(-t)*sympy.sin(t)

F1 = sympy.integrate(f1*sympy.exp(-s*t), (t, 0, sympy.oo))
print('The Laplace Transform of')
sympy.pretty_print(f1)
print('is:')
sympy.pretty_print(F1)
print('or:') 
F = sympy.laplace_transform(f1, t, s, noconds=True)
sympy.pretty_print(F)

print('Plot of f(t)')
sympy.plot(f1);

invF = invL(F).subs({a: 2})
print('Surface Plot of the Laplace Transform of f(t):')
sympy.pretty_print(invF)

p = sympy.plot(f1.subs({a: 2}), invL(F).subs({a: 2}),
               xlim=(0, 20), ylim=(0, 3), show=False)
p[1].line_color = 'red'
p.show()
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n2y7n6jw5d0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question I'm going to use [SymPy Plotting Backend](https://sympy-plot-backends.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

```py
from sympy import *
from spb import *
init_printing()

var("t, omega, s, alpha")
expr = exp(-t) * sin(t)
res = laplace_transform(expr, t, s, noconds=True)
print(res)
# 1/((s + 1)**2 + 1)
```

The 3D plot you shown on your post is the absolute value of `res`:

1. We need to replace `s` with `alpha + I*omega`.
2. Usually, when plotting the absolute value of a complex function, there could be poles, as it is the case for your function (there are 2 of them). It means that the z-coordinate is going to explode towards infinity. Hence, we are going to use `zlim` to better visualize the function.
3. I'm also going to activate wireframe (or mesh) lines, to better visualize the curvatures.
4. I'm going to apply a colormap similar to what is shown on the video.
5. I'm going to use Plotly because it produces better results than Matplotlib for 3D plots, at least for this case and in this point in time.

```py
colorscale = [
    [0, "green"],
    [0.01, "orange"],
    [0.05, "red"],
    [1, "red"]
]
plot3d(
    abs(res.subs(s, alpha + I * omega)), (alpha, -2, 2), (omega, -2, 2), {"colorscale": colorscale},
    backend=PB, size=(600, 600), zlim=(0, 10),
    use_cm=True, colorbar=False, wireframe=True, zlabel="Abs")
```

[image]

Similarly, we can create a contour plot of the same quantity. However, because there are poles involved, it is a good idea to plot the logarithm of the absolute value. Here, I'm going to use Matplotlib, because it is superior to Plotly when it comes to contour plots.

```py
plot_contour(
    log(abs(res.subs(s, alpha + I * omega))), (alpha, -2, 2), (omega, -2, 2),
    "log(abs)", {"levels": 20},
    grid=False, n=300)
```

[image]

The module also exposes the [`plot_complex`](https://sympy-plot-backends.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/ccomplex.html#spb.ccomplex.complex.plot_complex) function, which creates [domain coloring plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring). In practice, it shows the absolute value of a complex function colored by its argument. 3D domain coloring plots are also known as analytic landscapes:

```py
plot_complex(
    res, (s, -2-2j, 2+2j), threed=True, real=False, imag=False, abs=True,
    backend=PB, zlim=(0, 10), size=(600, 600))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks a lot, it looks working with your code, but I get this when I try to run the first code: `No module named '_distutils_hack' ` then I can't plot any of the 3-D

Comment: Alright it seems you are the creator of `Sympy Plot Backends`, I just realize my mistake is installing spb it is different package, then I read more and do this `pip install sympy_plot_backends` it works now, but it seems it needs web browser. I am going to work out on this so it won't need browser to open the image. Thanks a lot for your great answer and work. One day I won't only ask questions in SO but also try to answer questions too like what you did to me today.

Comment: They all work, I only need to adjust the backend after reading the github repo and documentation into this: `backend=MB`, I prefer PyPlot since PlotlyJS took a long time and more memory. I can't define size with MB backend.